# Why are jQuery objects inherently unique?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Reading about jQuery objects from [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), it states that all jQuery objects are unique, even if they that "This is true even if the object was created with the same selector or contain references to the exact same DOM elements."

So for example, the following would equate to `false`:

> $( "#logo" ) === $( "#logo" )

Why are jQuery objects all unique?

Thanks

Comment: Because, OOP & references? And jQuery is making a new instance for each query result. This is why it's so important to "cache" them in variables during use.

Comment: All objects are unique, it's just how it is, different instances of "Object" are not the same, even if they contain the same.

Comment: Because *all* objects in *JavaScript* are unique.  `{} === {}` is `false`.  It's because while they may have the same data, they are not the *same* object.  They are different objects in memory.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's a great point as well, as it's not just the jQuery implementation but a language design in and of itself.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that the jQuery object that is returned is unique, but the DOM element contained within that result is the actual element in question.  For example, `$("a") === $("a")` returns false, but `$("a")[0] === $("a")[0]` returns true.  jQuery basically says, "find this element (or elements) and return a new jQuery object wrapping it."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because, essentially, jQuery is using the factory pattern which creates a new instance of a jQuery object from a selector each time you call it.

As these are different instances, they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
$( "#logo" ).get(0) === $( "#logo" ).get(0)
```

As far as I know this compares the original Javascript-DOM-Object like you get with e.g.

```
document.getElementById( "logo" ) === document.getElementById( "logo" )
```

Comment: Correct, but the *query result* is a different object. They just refer to the same DOM element.

Comment: Yes I understood that part, I was just wondering if there was any specific reason as to why similar objects were unique from each other. Turns out its because they are similar yet different. Who knew? :p